# CSS: translate relative to parent div

Tags: css, animation, position, transform, translate

I have this toolbar docked on the left. There is that little arrow that shows/hides this toolbar (animation). To hide the toolbar, I use a simple css transform in another class.

[image]

```
.graph-tools {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}

.graph-tools-hidden {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

The css of the little arrow is the following:

```
.tools-container-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;

    background-color: #4b98b1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;

    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}

.tools-container-toggler-hidden {
    ???
}
```

My question is: what should I have in the *.tools-container-toggler-hidden* class to make the button also move to the left, but to remain on the edge, so I can press it again? 
I tried with translate and calc, but translate works using the element own width/height so it doesn't really works. How can I translate, but relative to the parent? Thanks!

Edit:
Here is a part of the HTML.

```
<div class="graph-tools-container-wrapper">
   <div class="graph-tools-container">
      <!-- The show/hide toolbar button -->
      <div class="tools-container-toggler"
         ng-class="{'tools-container-toggler-hidden': menuOptions.menuClosed}"
         ng-model="menuOptions.menuClosed" ng-click="menuOptions.menuClosed=!menuOptions.menuClosed">
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size: 10px;" aria-hidden="true"
            ng-if="menuOptions.menuClosed"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" style="font-size: 10px;" aria-hidden="true"
            ng-if="!menuOptions.menuClosed"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-tools" ng-class="{'graph-tools-hidden': menuOptions.menuClosed}">
         [....]
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.graph-tools-container-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1002;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}

.graph-tools-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The first wrapper is the toolbar 'skeleton', the graph-tools keeps the actual content and the container is used to help me hide the graph-tools. This toolbar isn't really on the far left (there is a another menu there) so that's why I used this.

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well?

Comment: @LinkinTED I added the HTML too.

Comment: Does `.graph-tools-container` have a `position: relative` ?

Comment: @LinkinTED no, it has only the height/width properties.

Comment: Try adding that, then the `position: absolute` of `.tools-container-toggler` will be relative to `.graph-tools-container` (and not to the viewport). Then it might slide along with it's parent on closing...

Comment: @LinkinTED Tried. It moves along with the parent, but only half of it is visible => https://i.imgur.com/5x7c6I7.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this suits you.

I've added `position: relative;` to `.graph-tools-container`.
Then the absolute positioning of it's child `.graph-tools-container` will be relative to it's parent, not the viewport.

By default it's placed at a `left: 100%` instead of `right: 0`;
Then animate it to `left: 0;`

It might need some adjusting (use margin for that).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.graph-tools-container').on('click', function() {
    $('.graph-tools').toggleClass('graph-tools-hidden');
    $('.tools-container-toggler').toggleClass('tools-container-toggler-hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.graph-tools-container-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.graph-tools-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.graph-tools {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}

.graph-tools-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.tools-container-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #4b98b1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

.tools-container-toggler-hidden {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph-tools-container-wrapper">
  <div class="graph-tools-container">
    <!-- The show/hide toolbar button -->
    <div class="tools-container-toggler">
      x
    </div>
    <div class="graph-tools">
      [....]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP didn't specify he wanted to use jQuery, and seems to be using Angular.

Comment: True, it's only for demo... he is somehow adding the `.tools-container-toggler-hidden ` to `tools-container-toggler `. This demonstrates it is working. Since I don't know the complete code, I improvised so the demo works... :)

Comment: It's weird how on your example, the button stands on the gray border. Mine is half hidden. Why would be that?

Comment: Do you have a `overflow: hidden` on one of the parents?

Comment: @LinkinTED no, I gave you the entire CSS.

Comment: Do you have an online demo?

Comment: I just tried to make a jsfiddle but there it works fine (copy paste from my IDE). I don't understand...

Comment: Well, I did this:
- removed the 'relative' property
- added left: calc(100% - 22px); and left: -22px to the hidden class
Now it works. Magically, I guess. Thanks for your answer though, it was helpful. Have a good day!

Comment: Nice that you have it working, and great to see that you take afford yourself as well, that's how SO works :)